# Combine multiple rows for unique column into single row

Tags: mysql, grouping

I have a table which tracks a the return code from an application. I'm trying to figure out how to format a query to return the returncode for each day into a single row. Here is the example table:

```
ID  COMPUTER    RETURNCODE  DATE
--  --------    ----------  ----
1   computer1   0           May, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000
2   computer1   1           May, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000
3   computer1   1           May, 17 2013 00:00:00+0000
4   computer2   0           May, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000
5   computer2   4           May, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000
6   computer2   4           May, 17 2013 00:00:00+0000
7   computer3   0           May, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000
8   computer3   8           May, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000
9   computer3   0           May, 17 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

Here is the output I am trying to get with a query:

```
COMPUTER    2013-05-15    2013-05-16    2013-05-17
--------    ----------    ----------    ----------
computer1       0             1             1
computer2       0             4             4
computer3       0             8             0
```

I've created an example via sqlfiddle here:
SQL Fiddle Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44687/1/0

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called "pivoting" the data.  Here is a way to do it in MySQL:

```
SELECT computer,
       max(case when date = '2013-05-15' then returncode end),
       max(case when date = '2013-05-16' then returncode end),
       max(case when date = '2013-05-17' then returncode end)
FROM returncodes
group by computer
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks! I knew it was something simple..Didn't think about a pivot though..